# Make text bigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you make text bigger or the text inside the div ?

i really dont know, help me out guys

something like:

```
$('div.text'), { FontSize: '40px' }); // <--- this is not real code, just to show what i need
```

Comment: Have you read any documentation? http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Thanks to you, i'm reading it now! there is much cool stuff! thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery, the way you would do this would be to change the CSS for the div.  Here is a quick an dirty demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wjAqm/

The actual code is `$("#demo").css("font-size", "20px");`

Comment: Simple, clean and just what i need. Thanks going read more about it!

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById("node1").style.fontSize = "40px";
```

Comment: Not what i need, but +1 from me and +1 from a friend of mine.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.text').css('font-size','40px');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `css` function if you have jQuery availalbe. Here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/Pharaon/qLuBs/

```
$('#content').click(function() {
    $(this).css('fontSize', '40px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#div1').css('fontSize', '20px');
```

Answer (score 1):

Little Zoom demo:

```
<button id="bigger">Zoom In</button><button id="smaller">Zoom Out</button>
<div id="text" style="font-size: 1em;">Hello, world.</div>

​<script>

$('#bigger').click( function() { zoom( 1.2 ); } );
$('#smaller').click( function() { zoom( 0.8 ); } );

function zoom( factor ) {
    var div = $('#text');
    var size = div.css( 'font-size' );
    size = parseFloat( size );
    console.log([ 'size', size ]);
    size *= factor;
    div.css( 'font-size', size + 'px' )
}
​</script>
```

Needs jQuery 1.7.x. [Live demo on jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxHWr/4/).

Comment: The code above works; I just forgot to save the jfiddle. Fixed.